# LNK2019 VS2012 error (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I've made 2 projects:
one is the provider, inside I've added a class DH:

```
using namespace std;
#ifdef PROVIDER_EXPORTS
#define DH_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DH_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include <iostream>

namespace Provider
{
    class DH
    {
    public:
        static DH_API std::string GetKey();
    };
}
```

and Imp:

```
#include "DH.h"

using namespace std;
namespace Provider
{


    std::string DH::GetKey()
    {

        return "KEY";
    }

}
```

when I dumpbin the dll I get:

```
?GetKey@DH@Provider@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ = @ILT+10(?GetKey@DH@Provider@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
```

On a new Project - the tester
I include dh.h
I've added the debug folder of the Provider project to the link directories

and I just call `DH::GetKey` but when I compile I get:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Provider::DH::GetKey(void)" (__imp_?GetKey@DH@Provider@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "long __stdcall WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: have you set up project dependencies or added your dll's .lib file to the tester project?

Comment: @spiritwolfform, Please post this as answer... I forgot about the .lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up project dependencies or add your dll's .lib file to the `tester` project's lib input so it knows where to search for the imported functions

Answer (score 0):

You miss an imported GetKey() function. There is a Project References section and you shall add the project that defines that function.